# PHP Mail function only working some of the time

Tags: php, email

I have a simple form with a simple mail function:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$message= $_REQUEST['message'] ;

mail( "$webmaster_email", "Website Form", "From: noreply@mysite.com",
   "From: $email  \n 
Name: $name \n
Phone: $phone\n 
Message: $message\n ");

header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
```

However, when I test I only rarely receive mail from it and it seems to get stuck - ie: it does not redirect to the thankyou page.

I have placed echos for testing and everything works right up to the mail() function.

I have checked with my hosting provider and there is no mail queue and PHP Apache is working as normal. Obviously, I have also checked my spam folders as well.

Would anyone know why this would only be working some of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the 3rd and 4th parameter of the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. The third parameter should contain the message and the fourth the additional headers. As you are sending the message and all (user provided...) variables in the 4th parameter, that is likely to lead to the problems you are having.

You should be able to change it swapping the parameters:

```
mail($webmaster_email, "Website Form",
     "From: $email  \n 
       Name: $name \n
       Phone: $phone\n 
       Message: $message\n ",
     "From: noreply@mysite.com");
```

You should also add error handling; the `mail()` function returns `true` or `false` depending on successful acceptance for delivery so you could simply log the times it returns `false` to troubleshoot.